# How to handle session in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I am using SQLAlchemy to connect with my google-cloud-sql instance. But by using MySQLDB + MySQL dialect we cannot have more than 12 concurrent connections per instance. So how can I handle SQLAlchemy sessions in the above scenario.